# How to hardware decode h264 video on Intel GPUs using GStreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I'm new to GStreamer and hardware decoding and started with [Playback tutorial 8: Hardware-accelerated video decoding](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/playback/hardware-accelerated-video-decoding.html?gi-language=python)

As far I understand I need to use one of the hardware accelerated plugins.
I would like to smoothly playback 1080p videos on OSX and Windows 10 operating systems for now, taking advantage of Intel GPUs for decoding (e.g. Intel Iris, Intel HD Graphics 620, etc.)

As far as I understand I should be able to use either the VAAPI or OpenMAX plugins ?

This what I've tried on OSX so far and where I got confused/stuck:

- I've compiled from source `gstreamer`, `gst-plugins-base`, `gst-plugins-good`, `gst-plugins-bad`, `gst-plugins-ugly`. after a few compile errors (due to some dependencies) that worked out
- I've attempted compiling `gstreamer-vaapi` and got to a dependency error (`checking for LIBVA... configure: error: Package requirements (libva >= 0.39.0 libva != 0.99.0) were not met`). I've attempted to compile [`libva`](https://github.com/intel/libva) and was met another dependency error: `configure: error: Package requirements (libdrm >= 2.4) were not met` when then lead me to try to compile [`drm`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/drm/) which threw another dependency error: `configure.ac:35: error: must install xorg-macros 1.12 or later before running autoconf/autogen`. This is where I'm not sure how far the rabbit hole goes. Attempting to compile `mesa/drm` makes me think this mainly for Linux and might not be supported on OSX ? Is this correct ? Can I use `libva` and `gstreamer-vaapi` to hardware decode 1080p H264 videos on OSX ? (What about Windows) ?
- Trying to compile `gst-omx` throws `stomxvideodec.c:41:10: fatal error: 'gst/gl/egl/gstglmemoryegl.h' file not found`. I've found `gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/gl/egl/gstglmemoryegl.h` but I'm unsure how to point `gst-omx` to this location.

Is it possible to hardware decode 1080p H264 videos on OSX and Windows with GStreamer on Intel GPUs ? If so, what's the simplest method ?

Comment: On macOS try `vtdec_h264`. Note that these hardware decoders heavily depend on OS and GPU. There is no one-for-all solution.

Comment: `vaapi` is for Linux and `omx` is for platforms that support omx (usually embedded platforms). So these won't get you anywhere on macOS. For intel cards. There are plugins for the intel media SDK. You need to get the SDK and build the plugins yourself due to licensing limitations - but that may work or windows.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications on `vaapi` and `omx` @FlorianZwoch. 
I'll give the Media SDK a go on Windows and see how I fare